# Long header text table not fix with

Tags: html, css

I have a tale in [codepen](https://codepen.io/pirgar704/pen/OJWNojE), my table have long header text.
How can I fixed with header table `th` dynamically because The number of columns in my table is not fixed ?

Comment: This `kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk` Is a single word. How will CSS divide one word. Add spaces between them.

Comment: I do not understand this question. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @ Manas Khandelwal  your answer help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces between the text.
Please use "word-wrap: break-word" style into you header for word break.

```
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100px
}
```

Comment: @moosa, Please use "word-wrap: break-word;" in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Please add following CSS code for word breaking

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

you can check [this url](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap) for more details.